# How to change the GeoServer port number in the "Mac OS X installer" version

Tags: geoserver, installation, mac, osx

There is a version of GeoServer available at http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/installation/osx_installer.html which is very simple to install on a Mac, only requiring the application to be dragged to the Applications folder and opened.

The only options within the GeoServer application itself are Start/Stop, and GeoServer defaults to using port 8080.

Is it possible to change the port number that is used by GeoServer in this version?

Comment: I'm not sure whether this version is using Tomcat or Jetty as the web server, or even something bundled into the application itself?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644114/change-jetty-default-port

Comment: @IanTurton that answer says to look for the file `$JETTY_HOME/etc/jetty.xml` but `$JETTY_HOME` isn't set in my case so the file doesn't exist there. A system-wide search for `jetty.xml` doesn't show anything. Are you sure that the above answer applies for the Mac version of GeoServer? Thanks

Comment: where did you install jetty? I'm not a Mac user so I can't help much more.

Comment: That's the crux of this question I guess. I didn't actually install Jetty, which doesn't seem to be a requirement for the Mac version. The Mac application may bundle its own web server (?) in which case the question is how to change its port number, or whether that's even possible.

Comment: The geoserver installer installs jetty for you - all you need to do is find it (hint look for a folder called geoserver) and change the port there following the instructions in the other answer.

Comment: @IanTurton thanks for the tips, which helped me to find the solution. I didn't realise that you can actually interrogate the contents of a Mac application, which indeed does bundle Jetty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I learnt that you can see the contents of an app in a Mac's Applications directory via Terminal:

`$ ls /Applications/GeoServer.app`

The file holding the GeoServer port number is `Contents/Java/start.ini`, so it's possible to edit this in admin mode using `sudo vi start.ini`. Search for the `jetty.port` section, edit the port number, save the file, and start GeoServer normally.

GeoServer is then available at the specified port number (eg http://localhost:8181/geoserver/web).

It may be a little unstable - for example I noticed that the Start/Shutdown options are both unavailable, and the status text always reads "GeoServer is starting". But this is good enough for my testing purposes.

[image]